# Can I create cascaded and dependent entries in a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, csproj

although I have a concrete case that I want to solve this is a more generic question.

I have a text template that creates a C# file. The text template loads an xml which is also included in the project. Currently anytime I edit the xml and save it, I have to go to the text template and also save it to update my C# file.

In the project the settings are for the C# file that it is  the text template, but I guess that this is only a reference to display the items correctly in the Solution Explorer. If I now edit the project file and put also a  to the text template to depend upon the XML file, it get the correct structure.

The only problem is, that if I save the XML, the text template is not automatically triggered. So the question is, if there is a possibility to link the items so that I get cascaded updates, so that I only have to modify the XML and the rest is updated accordingly?

This is now my special case, but in the end the question is, if there is a possibility in general?

Thanks
Martin